# How to determine user has clicked DataGridView but not a Cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, mouseclick-event

I want to prompt the user to enter new elements into a databound collection when they click in the empty area of a `DataGridView`.  How can I find out if the user has clicked inside of the `DataGridView` (the grey area by default), but not in a `Column`/`Row`/`Cell`?

Comment: you can check the e.Originalsource property of change eventhandler..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `MouseClick` event and do a hit test for it.

```
private void dgv_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var ht = dgv.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (ht.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.None)
    {
         //clicked on grey area
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To determine when the user has clicked on a blank part of the DataGridView, you're going to have to handle its `MouseUp event`.

In that event, you can HitTest the click location and watch for this to indicate `HitTestInfo.Nowhere`.

For example:

```
private void myDataGridView_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //'#See if the left mouse button was clicked
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        //'#Check the HitTest information for this click location
        if (myDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y) == HitTestInfo.Nowhere) {
            // Do what you want
        }
    }
}
```